# How to add custom words behind product price

Tags: opencart

I am trying to figure out how to add "Per Square Feet" behind the Product Price. It should be only applied to selected products - not to all. Any help is appreciated.

[This is the screenshot for reference](http://postimg.org/image/tnfsjap39/)

Comment: In OpenCart it is possible to define an *amount unit*, i.e. *inch*, *foot*, etc. By defining this it should be possible to display this *property* in your product details screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the photo it helped a lot. I suggest adding this into vqmod/vqcache. For more information on VQmod look here: https://code.google.com/p/vqmod/. If not you can just take the HTML, PHP, and Query code and put it directly in your core files.

View:

```
<file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/product.tpl"> // where it will insert the below code
<operation>
<search position="before"><![CDATA[<?php if ($tax) { ?>]]></search> // this places your code before the code in the CDATA[....what ever is here....]
<add><![CDATA[ // the below code is what you are adding
<?php if isset($pricePerSqFt) { ?>
<p><?php echo $pricePerSqFt; ?></p>]]></add>
</operation>
</file>
```

Controller:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');
$this->data['pricePerSqFt'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getData();
```

Model:

```
<file name="catalog/model/catalog/product.php">
<operation>
<search position="after"><![CDATA[class ModelCatalogProduct extends Model {]]></search>
<add>
<![CDATA[
public function getData() {
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT what_data_you_want FROM table_name"); // will grab the data from database
if (isset($query)) {
return $query;
}else{
return NULL;
}
} 
]]>
</add>
</operation>
</file>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Really appreciate it. But i don't really understand where should i add the codes that you give for catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/product.tpl & catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/product.tpl. I cant find any CDATA. Can you explain to me more specifically.

Comment: Look for an OpenCart extension here: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension. CDATA is XML syntax. VQmod is a XML parser that finds code in a document and then adds code into the document (e.g. looks for the exact phrase "some phrase" and then after/ before/ replaces it with your "new phrase"). The only difference between those two examples is instead of plain english it is injecting code. This is done so you don't manually change your OpenCart core files (which can be annoying and time consuming). The extension you download will basically use the same code as my example.